# How to load a component with flags multiple times in the same page in Elm?

Tags: elm

Is there a way to build components for a page with Elm and to compile two components in the same Elm file as well as loading twice the same component with the same code?

Do you know how I could do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

elm-make let you select multiple files that you want to compile together.

```
elm-make Header.elm Footer.elm Button.elm --output=app.js
```

**Header.elm**

```
port module Header exposing (..)

import Html


main =
    Html.div [] [ Html.text "Header" ]
```

**Footer.elm**

```
port module Footer exposing (..)

import Html


main =
    Html.div [] [ Html.text "Footer" ]
```

**Button.elm**

```
port module Button exposing (..)

import Html


main =
    Html.div [] [ Html.button [] [ Html.text "Button" ] ]
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Elm Demo</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="button"></div>
    <div id="button2"></div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
  </body>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
  <script>
      let header = Elm.Header.embed(document.getElementById("header"));
      let footer = Elm.Footer.embed(document.getElementById("footer"));
      let button = Elm.Button.embed(document.getElementById("button"));
      let button2 = Elm.Button.embed(document.getElementById("button2"));
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: About the flags, you can use a `Html.programWithFlags` and pass the flags as a second parameter to `embed()`

Comment: Does each embed get its own Elm runtime, or does one runtime service them all?